# Alternative solution for <fr:currency>

Tags: xpath, xforms, orbeon

We have performance issue using  for controls which gets number in the format of $dollars as input. In-order to over come this performance issue we used   instead of  and implemented the following calculate functionality in the bind of the control.

```
<xforms:bind id="Amount" 
             nodeset="instance('sample_form')/Amounts/Amount" 
             calculate="if (. !=0) 
                        then format-number(xs:double(.),'$#,##0.000') 
                        else ."/>
```

But the problem with the above code is, its converting the control's value into String type which leads to error in the controls which has its value dependent on this. Kindly provide me a solution for the above problem or provide a better recommendation to handle this situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to show the formatted value (which I assume to be the case since you are thinking of using a `calculate`), then you could put that expression you have on the `calculate` inside an:

```
<xforms:output value="..."/>
```

If you need both input and output, and you'd like the value stored in your instance to be just the unformatted number, then I don't think there is an easy way around using `<fr:currency>` other than somehow reimplementing the functionality provided by `<fr:currency>`. If you need both input and output, then I would recommend you to investigate this further to find, and then solve, the source of the performance issue.